# Wait for back image to be loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image

I got this line in my javascript:

```
$("#botbg").css("background-image", "url(/png/" + epage + ".jpg)");
```

"botbg" is a div.
is it possible to attach a callback to this function? I simply want other operations to wait till this is finished.

these werent succesfull:

```
$("#botbg").css("background-image", "url(/png/" + epage + ".jpg)").load(function(){
//...
});

$("#botbg").css("background-image", "url(/png/" + epage + ".jpg)").one("load", function(){
//...
});

$("#botbg").css("background-image", "url(/png/" + epage + ".jpg)").ready(function(){
//...
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
var img = new Image();
img.src = url;
img.onload = function( ) {
    $("#botbg").css("background-image", "url(" + url + ")");
}
```

Comment: a alert after "function(){" doesnt fire:S

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't.

The best thing you can do is to load your image inside a temp div then set your background image with when the load callback is called like this :

```
<div id="tmp"><img src="/png/yourimage.jpg" /></div>

$("#tmp").load(function(){
    $("#botbg").css("background-image", "url(/png/yourimage.jpg)");
});
```

**EDIT**

New way to call .load() function

```
<div id="tmp"><img src="/png/yourimage.jpg" /></div>

$("#tmp").on("load", function() {
    $("#botbg").css("background-image", "url(/png/yourimage.jpg)");
});
```

Comment: While this solution might work it's not advised because [load()](http://api.jquery.com/load-event/) is **Deprecated** and it doesn't work consistently nor reliably cross-browser.

Comment: Ok, I didn't know that, I have updated my answer acc. to this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12643160/load-method-deprecated

Comment: Aren't you just testing if div _tmp_ has loaded rather than testing if the img has loaded?

Comment: Yeah, I am using this code on my web site, but your solution is better than mine => +1

Comment: Unfortunately that fixes only half of the problem. Using it with `.on('load')` doesn't make the event any more reliable for use in conjunction with images. Check out the **Caveats of the load event when used with images** notice on the docs page here: http://api.jquery.com/load-event/

Answer (score 0):

In jQuery the callback functions are only applied to `asynchronous` tasks and since the `css` function is a `synchronized` function there is no such thing as callback, and as such every line of code you put after the `.css()` function will be called immediately.

You can however track the load of your background-image, but even doing so it's not guaranteed that your code will be executed after the image is showing, specially in big images where the browser would take some time to `render` the image. To track if your image is loaded you can do something like the following:

```
$img = $('<img src="/png/'+epage+'.jpg" id="myImg"/>');//now it will work
$img.bind('load',function(){
    $("#botbg").css("background-image", "url(/png/" + epage + ".jpg)");
});
```

Here's a functional [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/brunovieira/nj6Z6/).

I hope it helped. Cheers

Comment: i put a alert after the callback.. it doesnt fire:S

Comment: I'm sorry, I'll edit to make it right. Dumb me forgot an important detail