# showing image length zero when i tried to reload

Tags: jquery, html

I am beginner and i am trying to display the width of the image. when i load for the first time it is giving correct width and if i reload it is displaying width as 0. Again when i try to load with chrome option "empty cache and hard reload" it is displaying correct width. Please unveil the mystery, i couldn't understand.

```
<html>
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
#latest_albums{

overflow: hidden;
margin: 1em 1em;
background-color: #009999;
}

.album li{
list-style-type: none;
float: left;
overflow: hidden;
margin: 2px 2px 0px 0px;
position: relative;


}

</style>

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <div id="latest_albums">

        <div class="album">
            <div class="set1">
            <li> <img src="albums/image1.jpg"> </li>
            <li> <img src="albums/image2.jpg"> </li>
            <li> <img src="albums/image3.jpg"> </li>
            <li> <img src="albums/image4.jpg"> </li>

            <li> <img src="albums/image5.jpg"> </li>
            <li> <img src="albums/image6.jpg"> </li>
</div>
<div class="set2">
            <li> <img src="albums/image1.jpg"> </li>
            <li> <img src="albums/image2.jpg"> </li>
            <li> <img src="albums/image3.jpg"> </li>
            <li> <img src="albums/image4.jpg"> </li>

            <li> <img src="albums/image5.jpg"> </li>
            <li> <img src="albums/image6.jpg"> </li>
</div>
        </div>

    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
var i=0,w = -150,SCROOL_WIDTH,WIN_WIDTH,IMG_MARGIN,IMG_WIDTH=10,TOT_ALBUMS,ALBUM_WIDTH;

IMG_WIDTH = $("div.album li").eq(0).width();

console.log(IMG_WIDTH);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

thanks ,
ravi

Answer (score 0):

You should wait until the image is loaded before getting it's width (otherwise it wil return 0, because it doesn't know it's sizes). Try this:

```
$("div.album li:first img").load(function(){
    IMG_WIDTH = $("div.album li").eq(0).width();
    console.log(IMG_WIDTH);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
   var i=0,w = -150,SCROOL_WIDTH,WIN_WIDTH,IMG_MARGIN,IMG_WIDTH=10,TOT_ALBUMS,ALBUM_WIDTH;

   IMG_WIDTH = $("div.album li").eq(0).width();

   console.log(IMG_WIDTH);
});
</script>
```

There is also event handler `image.onload` that is executed when image is loaded. Sometimes even `image.onload` is not triggered so you can use timer to check when image width gets over 0. Check this: [jQuery or Javascript check if image loaded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20613984/jquery-or-javascript-check-if-image-loaded)