# How to receive the error event for not loaded images at top performance

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to replace the `src` attribute of all `<img>` elements in a certain element, that have not been loaded, because the source was not found (404).

There are quite a few topics on this here:

- [Check if an image is loaded (no errors) in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1977871/check-if-an-image-is-loaded-no-errors-in-javascript)
- [jQuery or Javascript check if image loaded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20613984/jquery-or-javascript-check-if-image-loaded)

Most of the answers add an eventListener on the images that wait for an `error` event. Ideally we'd just write something like this:

---

### ***Not working example* of an delegated event listener:**

```
$("#element").on("error", "img", function(){
   console.log("hey, there was an error in this image: "+$(this));
})
```

[Another user was kind enough to point this out.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20614371/3244925)

This is not working because [the `error` event seem not to bubble](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#event-type-error), like the `click` event for example.

---

So with this knowlege, the only thing left seems to be, to iterate each image and check it for errors.

### Whats the point (tl;dr)?

And here my  question: What is the fasted method to iterate all images of a certain object for errors with javascript (yes, you may use jQuery). By fastest I mean: the iteration should be quite quick and unnecessary event listeners should not be placed (my problem).

This is my example code:

```
$(function(){
    var $element = $("#element");
    var replaceImgSrc = "http://www.placehold.it/100x100&text=replaced";
    var allImages = $element.find("img");

    for (var i = 0; i < allImages.length; i++) {
        $(allImages[i]).one('error', function () {
            $(this).attr("src", replaceImgSrc).addClass("not-loaded")
        });
    }
});
```

And here is a jsFiddleDemo: http://jsfiddle.net/qq2ccx05/
The performance in the jsFiddle is awful, it's better in production.

I'd like to know if there is a smarter way to solve this problem.

Comment: I think this is OK. To make it look better you could add height and width to the <img> so it looks less... well you know ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could capture 'onerror' event, doesn't seem really more optimized:

```
var replaceImgSrc = "http://www.placehold.it/100x100&text=replaced";
$('#element')[0].addEventListener(
    'error',
    function(event){
        var elm = event.target;
        if( elm.tagName == 'IMG'){
            elm.src = replaceImgSrc;
        }
    },
    true // Capture event
);
```

### jsFiddle

Comment: Amazing, this looks very sleek and don't add an event listener to each node. Very nice, thank you!