# How to capture 404 (not found) error returned by an img tag which is inside an iframe

Tags: javascript

Consider i have an iframe tag with src.
iframe src belongs to same domain.. No cross domain.

if the iframe document has image tag which returns not found error. 
How should i capture this error in javascript on my page.
i am trying to do it this way. But there is nothing in console except get error for image.

```
document.body.onload=function(){
     if(document.getElementById('myiframe')){
     var y = document.getElementById('myiframe').contentWindow ||     document.getElementById('myiframe').contentDocument;
     var z= y.document.getElementsByTagName('img');
     for(var i=0; i<z.length; i++){
     console.log(z[i]);
     z[i].onerror= function(){
        console.log('here');
      }
     }
    }
   }
```

Comment: Look here for usage of onError http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3984287/how-to-show-alternate-image-if-source-image-is-not-found-onerror-working-in-ie

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [**Image complete Property**](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_img_complete.asp) to test if it's loaded or not:

```
if(document.getElementById("myImg").complete){
    alert("Image is loaded correctly !!!");
} else  alert("An error occured while loading Image !!!");
```

Or you can use the `new Image()` constructor and its `onerror()` method:

```
var image = new Image();
image.onerror = function () {
   console.error("Cannot load image");
   //do something else...
}
image.src = "path/image.jpg";
```

Here is [the original answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20614284/3669624).

Answer (score 0):

You can capture image fail in iframe and from iframe call one function from parent

```
$('img').error(function(){parent.imageNotLoaded()})
```

Comment: i neeet to just check if all images in iframe are loaded without any error