# how load function behaviour in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i have html code and jquery to show and hide a form based on image loaded or not loaded like this

```
...
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="bootstrap/js/jquery.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

$("#image11")
.load(function(){
    alert('oke1');
    $("#upload1").hide();
    $("#image21").hide();

})
.error(function(){
    alert('oke2');
    $("#image11").hide();
    $("#upload1").hide();
    $("#image21")
        .load(function(){
            alert('oke3');
            $("#upload1").hide();

            $("#image11").hide();
    })
    .error(function(){
        alert('oke4');
            $("#upload1").show();
            $("#image21").hide()
            $("#image11").hide();
      });
   });

})

            </script>
 <body>
     <div class="col-sm-5 col-xs-7">
     <img src="foto_peserta/tes.jpg" width="100"   id="image11"  alt="tes"/>
     <img src="foto_peserta/cek.jpg" width="100" id="image21"  alt="tes2"/>          
  </div>
<div id="upload1">
<form method="post" name="form1" action="<?php echo  $editFormAction; ?>"  enctype="multipart/form-data"><img id="previewHolder"  alt="Foto" width="100px" height="100px"/> <p>
   <input type="file" name="foto_peserta" id="foto_peserta"  required>
   <p class="help-block">maximum image size is 50 kB,only JPG, JPEG, PNG &amp; GIF files are allowed</p>
   <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Upload Foto</button>
              <input type="hidden" name="MM_update" value="form1" >
              <input type="hidden"  name="id_personal" value="<?php echo $row_foto_peserta_tampil['id_personal']; ?> ">
    </form></div>


 </body>
 </html>
```

I just confused why every time i refresh the page (when my image21 is load and my image11 not loaded) the alert `('oke2')`  prompt but not with `alert('oke3')`, is anything wrong with my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The load function you are talking about is deprecated since jQuery 1.8:

- http://api.jquery.com/load-event/  (see the category of the article)
- [jQuery or Javascript check if image loaded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20613984/jquery-or-javascript-check-if-image-loaded)

In later versions only one `.load()` function is left into jQuery, to avoid ambiguity, it is used to load data from another source http://api.jquery.com/load/ for example if you need to load text coming from your server into a div in your page.

You can check if an image loaded by using

```
$('img.mustLoad').on('load',function(){
        /* Fire your image resize code here */
});
```

This very complicated snippet is taken from the currently second answer of the question i posted above so credit is due to "Alex W". This should work with every version of jQuery

to handle loading errors you need to use a separate event

```
$('img.mustLoad').on('error',function(){
        /* Fire your image resize code here */
});
```

So you need to edit your code accordingly