# Sliding image from left to right

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I'm facing an issue with sliding an image from left to right.

**What do I want**: Image should slide from the left side of the screen to the right side.

My code is:

```
$('image').show("slide", { direction: "right" }, 1200);
```

But this solution is not working a per the expectations. Image slides from left to right, but not the whole image is loaded and the full image is visible only at the end of the animation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here you can check:

```
 $('#hello').show('slide', {direction: 'right'}, 1000);

you can also  use: toggle

$(".slide-toggle").click(function(){
        $(".box").animate({
            width: "toggle"
        });

   or:

   $(".slidingDiv").toggle("slide");
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `animate` instead of `show` as using show will show complete image after the animation

```js
$('#image').animate({right:'0px'},1200)
```

```css
img{
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  position: absolute
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<img id="image" src="https://yt3.ggpht.com/-v0soe-ievYE/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/OixOH_h84Po/s900-c-k-no-mo-rj-c0xffffff/photo.jpg"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("img").animate({
    marginLeft: "0px"
  }, 2000);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="frame" style="width: 300px; height:300px; overflow:hidden;">
  <img id="image" src="https://www.filterforge.com/more/help/images/size400.jpg" style='margin-left:-300px; height: 100%; width: 100%; '>
  </img>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is that the animation started before image object was loaded completely to the browser.
You should check out jquery load event: https://api.jquery.com/load-event/
And search for answers for question "jquery image load callback",
e.g.: [jQuery or Javascript check if image loaded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20613984/jquery-or-javascript-check-if-image-loaded)

In my opinion the best way is create image object with JS, push it to DOM element and start animation, when image will be loaded completely.

In short:

```
$("<img/>")
.attr("src", "/images/your-image.jpg")
.on('load', function() { startAnimation() })
.appendTo($('#imageContainer'));

var startAnimation = function(){
$('#hello').show('slide', {direction: 'right'}, 1000);
}
```