# What is the .load() equvalent function in firefox browser(All versions)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, firefox

The below code does not alert the message in firefox especially version - 39.0.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#test').load(function(){
            alert('loaded');
    });
});

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img class="content_tag" id="test" src="ACTUAL IMAGE PATH"/>
```

Answer (score 3):

First of all Your jquery library should be before your code like this:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#test').attr('src', 'http://www.youtube.com/v/h60r2HPsiuM');
    $('#test').load(function(){
            alert('loaded');
    });
});
</script>
<img class="content_tag" id="test" src="ACTUAL IMAGE PATH"/>
```

Please check this out [Bug #11733](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/11733) and [SO discussion on this bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12643160/load-method-deprecated) which states that .load() is depreciated now and .on('load') replaces it.

```
$('#test').on('load',function(){
     alert('loaded');
});
```

Comment: But that doesnt solved my problem. Can you check the fiddle -
http://jsfiddle.net/sanjaykumarns/4x4uLmzu/3/ which is working in chrome but not in firefox 39.0.

Comment: @SanjayKumarNS I have checked your fiddle in version 39.0 of firefox also, For me it is working fine for every version and browser.

Comment: Thanks  Rohit Arora for the reply. I found the solution that, in firefox, .load() should contain the first parameter should be the url- like this - http://jsfiddle.net/sanjaykumarns/4x4uLmzu/4/

Comment: @SanjayKumarNS Checkout my edit now. Because passing url to load function is not the correct solution as it is another method to load something in your specific element.