# CSS/JS won't work if I include the header

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, include

Here is my `index.html` file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset=utf-8>
    <title>title</title>
    <meta name=viewport content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta http-equiv=X-UA-Compatible content="IE=edge">
    <link href=assets/css/elegant-icons.min.css rel=stylesheet type=text/css media="all"/>
    <link href=assets/css/bootstrap.css rel=stylesheet type=text/css media="all"/>
    <link href=assets/css/theme.css rel=stylesheet type=text/css media="all"/>
    <link rel=stylesheet type=text/css href="assets/css/style.css"/>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="inc"></div>

    <div class=main-container>
      <section class="no-pad coming-soon fullscreen-element">


      </section>
    </div>

    <script src=assets/js/jquery.min.js></script>
    <script src=assets/js/bootstrap.min.js></script>
    <script src=assets/js/smooth-scroll.min.js></script>
    <script src=assets/js/scripts.js></script>
    <script>
      $(function(){
        $("#inc").load("header.html");   
      });
    </script> 
  </body>
</html>
```

If I copy-paste the content of `header.html` page after the body, then everything works fine.

when I tried to include the `header.html` page using **`.load()`** function then the CSS won't work properly.

Here is the online sample [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LRVQoN)
if I include the content of `div="inc"` from an external file like `header.html` than drop-down menu will overlap each other.

Comment: And what is inside `header.html` ?

Comment: I think its not `laod()`. It should be `load()`.

Comment: Share an example please

Comment: @Harsh, as per my knowledge `load()` method is already depricated in latest jquery. See (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12643160/load-method-deprecated).

Comment: thanks for comment, In header file i have some div with contented like drop-down menu after including the layout of drop-down menu is not perfect. with the code in same file everything is working fine

Comment: Thanks @Samir but than how i will include my header, is there any other alternative i am not using php.

Comment: Added one answer, Try using like that.

Comment: Please provide the `header.html` as well in order to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Hope this helps.

Your `scripts.js` file contains

```
$(window).load(function(){

  "use strict";
    // Align Elements Vertically

    alignVertical();
    alignBottom();

    $(window).resize(function(){
        alignVertical();
        alignBottom();
    });

    // Isotope Projects
});
```

The `scripts.js` file you have provided is trying to add some styling to the `header.html`.

but it's not doing the expected behaviour because the `scripts.js` file is loading before the `header.html` file.

Just add this at the end after your header content

```
<script src=assets/js/scripts.js></script>
```

This will let the `header.html` content load first and than `scripts.js`

Also here is the github repo code structure

https://github.com/siddhartharora02/jsLoad

Answer (score 0):

## Try this

```
<link href="../assets/css/elegant-icons.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all"/>
<link href="../assets/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all"/>
<link href="../assets/css/theme.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../assets/css/style.css"/>

<script src="../assets/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="../assets/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="../assets/js/smooth-scroll.min.js"></script>
<script src="../assets/js/scripts.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using like this,

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.get('header.html').success(function(data){
           var headerHTML = data;
           $('#inc').html(headerHTML);
    });
});
```

Comment: The same code is not showing anything also there is no error in console Please explain what #div_content means ? where I have to declare this div in my code I am using a div call "inc"

Comment: The answer has been edited. Please check it once in your page. This is working fine for me.

Comment: by this the header will include but the layout problem not solved here is the sample code you can check it http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LRVQoN

Answer (score 0):

**For your original issue,**

If you want to include `html` content dynamically, here is a method to do it,

HTML,

```
<link data-include="includes/header.html">
```

JS,

```
$('link[data-include]').each(function(){
    var el = $(this),
        template = $(this).data('include');

    $.get(template, function(data){
        $(el).replaceWith(data);
    });
});
```

Hope this will help!

---

### Try this,

Now you can include any partial content as you want.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset=utf-8>
<title>title</title>
<meta name=viewport content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<meta http-equiv=X-UA-Compatible content="IE=edge">
<link href=assets/css/elegant-icons.min.css rel=stylesheet type=text/css media="all"/>
<link href=assets/css/bootstrap.css rel=stylesheet type=text/css media="all"/>
<link href=assets/css/theme.css rel=stylesheet type=text/css media="all"/>
<link rel=stylesheet type=text/css href="assets/css/style.css"/>
</head>
<body>

<link data-include="header.html">

<div class=main-container>
<section class="no-pad coming-soon fullscreen-element">


</section>
</div>

<script src=assets/js/jquery.min.js></script>
<script src=assets/js/bootstrap.min.js></script>
<script src=assets/js/smooth-scroll.min.js></script>
<script src=assets/js/scripts.js></script>
<script>
$(function(){
  $('link[data-include]').each(function(){
    var el = $(this),
        template = $(this).data('include');

    $.get(template, function(data){
        $(el).replaceWith(data);
    });
  });   
});
</script> 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for answering, This is including my header like .load() function but  unfortunately I am facing the layout issue in this also.

Comment: OK can you provide the actual sample? Because without looking at it can't exactly say what is the issue. You can use something like https://jsbin.com/

Comment: I have multiple CSS/ JS file where i can upload my sample code. Sites like jsfiddle allows only single files.

Comment: You can add multiple files. And use jsbin. Because it shows full html. So its easy for us to check the file importing order.

Answer (score 0):

### How about this:

Instead of using a load method, use an iframe

```
<iframe id="inc" src="header.html" style="border:0; overflow:auto;"></iframe>
```

### Edit

```
<iframe id="inc" src="header.html" class="hidden"></iframe>
```

## css

```
iframe.hidden {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  border: 0;
  overflow: auto;
  display: hidden;
}

iframe.hidden.load {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  border: 0;
  overflow: auto;
  display: block;
}
```

### JS

!!! Here trigger means the trigger when you want it to load such as onClick, onMouseover, etc !!!

**Requires jQuery**

```
$('iframe.hidden').trigger(function() {
  $(this).addClass('load');  
});
```

Comment: Don't use iframe, unless you are load a page outside from your domain. :)

Comment: iframe is increasing the issue because it automatically loads <html><body> this type of tags so still facing layout issue

Comment: 1. You can style the frame using css and that can solve the issue

Comment: 2. You can add a class to the iframe that does display:hidden; and when you want it to load, use JS to change the style to display: block;