# Element by Name on load setting value

Tags: javascript, jquery

Trying to get the page to load with default selected option 2

Well neither are working, what's correct?

My HTML is like this, no ID or class

```js
$(window).load(function() {
  $("tour-adult[]").value = 3;
  document.getElementById("tour-adult[]").value = 4;
});
```

```html
<div class="tourmaster-combobox-wrap">
  <select name="tour-adult[]">
    <option value="">Adult</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
    <option value="6">6</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as your first attempt, try selecting the `select` element by it's `name` attribute and using jQuery's [val()](https://api.jquery.com/val/) method to set the value:

```
$("select[name='tour-adult[]']").val(3);
```

You currently don't have an `id` assigned to the select. If you want to go native, you'd use something like [querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector):

```
document.querySelector("select[name='tour-adult[]']").value = 4;
```

```js
$(window).on('load', function() {
  $("select[name='tour-adult[]']").val(3);
  
  console.log($("select[name='tour-adult[]']").val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="tourmaster-combobox-wrap">
  <select name="tour-adult[]">
    <option value="">Adult</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
    <option value="6">6</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Using jQuery:

- Use `.on('load', () {...}` instead of `.load()` - [Why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12643160/load-method-deprecated)
- Use an [attribute selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors) like `$("[attribute='attributeName']")`
- Pass the value as a String, not a Number

```js
$(window).on('load', function() {
  $('select[name="tour-adult[]"]').val('3');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="tourmaster-combobox-wrap">
  <select name="tour-adult[]">
    <option value="">Adult</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
    <option value="6">6</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks that's working. however it created another problem in calculation.... when i test to select other value from interface the calculation takes the new value + 2 
This is persons @ tour package so if i choose 3 after loading it will calculate 5 times

Comment: I'm afraid I don't follow what you mean - I don't know why something is being calculated here, input in `.val()` should match the `value` on your options

Answer (score 0):

If you want to call it by ID, you will need to add an ID. I removed your jquery and added an ID and its working.

```js
document.getElementById("tour-adult").value = 4;
```

```html
<div class="tourmaster-combobox-wrap">
  <select id="tour-adult" name="tour-adult[]">
    <option value="">Adult</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
    <option value="6">6</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: oh yea just edited the title, it's by name not by ID 
but same thing anyway you see it